# limit of $a_n = \left( \frac{ \sqrt{k} - 1 }{ \sqrt{k} + 1} \right )^n, \quad k\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

How to find the limit of the following sequence:

$a_n = \left(  \frac{ \sqrt{k} - 1 }{ \sqrt{k} + 1} \right )^n, \quad \text{for a constant } k\in \mathbb{N}$

$\begin{align}
a_n = \left(  \frac{ \sqrt{k} - 1 }{ \sqrt{k} + 1} \right )^n  &= 
a_n = \left(  \frac{ (\sqrt{k} - 1) (\sqrt{ k } - 1) }{ (\sqrt{k} + 1) (\sqrt{k} - 1) } \right )^n \\
&= a_n =  \frac{ (\sqrt{k} - 1 )^{2n}}{ (k - 1)^n} 
\end{align}$

I do not feel that it did help very much.

**Question**: How can I go on ?

Comment: So, $k$ is a constant and $n$ goes to infinity?

Comment: Are you sure that it is not $n$ instead of $k$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Notice that for  $k>1$, we have $0<\frac{\sqrt{k}-1}{\sqrt{k}+1}<1$ and it is independent of $n$

> Possible keyword: Geometric sequence.

Comment: in my analysis scriptum I can only find the geometric series and not the geometric sequence. 
So I have said since it is a geometric series the sequence has to go to $0$ for $n \to \infty$ and thus $a_n$ has a limit. But I fail finding that limit.

Comment: $0$ is the correct answer. it is also known as [geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression). Series usually refers to summation.